# determine not found queries when using multiple OR filters with LDAP

Tags: filter, ldap, ldap-query

So I am using LDAP to perform queries like `(|(anr=query 1)(anr=query 2)(anr=query 3))`. I get an arbitrary number of results back.

Is there a way to either:

- for each result determine which query resulted in it
- determine which query resulted in no results

I know I could do one query at a time but that is not very efficient.

Thanks!

Comment: Not using LDAP. Sure, I guess you could test each result to see which result Entry matched each Query.  Why not just do several queries? (LDAP is fast)

Comment: I know it is but I was hoping to make my 1000+ search queries faster.